# Hirarchical sorting in sql server when child id contains '.'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i have some childid  like below

```
childid
------------

1.1
1.2
2.8
2.7
6.5
6.5.1
6.5.15
7.1
8
```

sort order will be

```
childid 
--------
1.1
1.2
2.7
2.8
6.5
6.51
6.5.15
7.1
```

i tried to converted to intiger like below

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)='1.23.2';

set @str=(select replace(@str,'.',''))
select @str
```

but it fails when

```
7.1
8
```

comes 
it gives order like

```
8
7.1
```

but i need order like below

```
7.1
8
```

also if number like

```
7.1.1
7.1.8
6.7.7.7
```

then order should be

```
6.7.7.7
7.1.1
7.1.8
```

i hope somebody can help me to solve this

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY childid`?

Comment: @FelixPamittan what will be the result if  7.11 and 1111.11 is there ? the column is nvarchar type ?

Comment: What should it be? Using my comment, it'll be 111.1 then 7.11. Is this what not you're expecting?

Comment: @FelixPamittan no i need order like 7.11 first then 111.1 i need that way

Comment: Posted an answer but it only works for 2008 and up. It's probably worth [upgrading soon though](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/lifecycle?c2=1044) - 2005 only has about 6 months of extended support remaining - it fell out of mainstream support in 2011.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my db is 2008 so it is working , the problem is it fails when chilid contains some string or something like 1.23.22abc

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, the information, that your ids could be non-numeric too came very late... In my last edit you'll find an approach with padded strings too...

Comment: Why aren't you using `hierarchyid`? It exists precisely for this purpose and handles correctly sorting, updating of the hierarchy, querying for parents and children etc.You *can't* use a raw string in the way you did as a hierarchy key - keys must be fixed length or lexical sorting will fail as you found out

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the question is tagged with SQL2005...

Comment: @Shnugo that 10 year old version is *very* unsupported. It will cost less to upgrade to a newer version that can work in newer, 64-bit hardware than try to solve already solved problems. Eg. using hierarchy paths works only if the key length is fixed - OK for a binary representation, NOT OK for strings, unless the string has fixed length

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well... **I** know that, but the question still needs a solution for SQL2005 :-)

Comment: @Shnugo the key format is wrong. If the OP can't fix it, anything else is simply covering up. If there is a lot of data with that format, the fix will cost. If not, why not upgrade?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, we have absolutely no knowledge why the data is as it is, maybe it's coming from extern, maybe legacy, whatever... You may suggest an upgrade but you shouldn't insist... ;-)

Comment: @Shnugo I don't insist - the current scheme has issues : if non-numeric characters are allowed, sorting will fail eg for `6.5.1`, `6.5.2` and `6.5.15`. Your solution will treat all of them as strings and return 1,15,2 instead of 1,2,15

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no, please have a closer look. My solution will return a concatenated string, where each element ist right-padded with spaces to a length of 10. "1.15.2" will return as ".........1........15........2". This will lead to a clean alphanumerical sort order (just found, that many spaces are surpressed in this comment, replaced it with dots)

Comment: @Shnugo indeed - in fact the OP should replace the current scheme with the result of your function. This would allow indexing and allow eg child queries to become a simple `LIKE 'parentkey.%'`

Comment: ArunprasanthKV, maybe you want to read the last comment of @PanagiotisKanavos... Adding the results of my statement as a fix value to your datatable would speed up things and offer many benefits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

EDIT: I changed the approach to deal with non-numeric values like '123abc' too.

```
declare @ids table(idList varchar(100))
insert into @ids values
 ('1.1')
,('1.2')
,('2.8')
,('2.7')
,('6.5')
,('6.5.1')
,('6.5.15')
,('7.1')
,('8');

select idList,padded.OrderBy
from @ids as ids
cross apply(select cast('<r>' + replace(idList,'.','</r><r>') + '</r>' as xml)) as AsXml(val)
cross apply
(
    select right('                ' + rtrim(x.y.value('.','varchar(max)')),10) 
    from AsXml.val.nodes('/r') as x(y)
    for xml path('')
) as padded(OrderBy)
order by padded.OrderBy
```

Comment: Author mentioned that he has alphanumeric values like `1.23.22abc`. I think it will fail here `str(x.y.value('.','int'),5)`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, cannot find any hint like this? I think this is a matter of alphanumerical sorting, but all IDs are int.

Comment: You can see it comment to the question: `@Damien_The_Unbeliever my db is 2008 so it is working , the problem is it fails when chilid contains some string or something like 1.23.22abc`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, yes, this important information came quite late... Thnak you for the hint! Changed my approach to deal with padded string rather than padded int.

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution but it works for me:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( childid VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1.1' ),
        ( '1.2' ),
        ( '2.8' ),
        ( '2.7' ),
        ( '6.5' ),
        ( '6.5.1' ),
        ( '6.5.15' ),
        ( '7.1' ),
        ( '8' )

;WITH cte AS(SELECT childid + '.' AS childid FROM @t)
SELECT LEFT(childid, LEN(childid) - 1) AS childid
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('.', childid) i1) c1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN i1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CHARINDEX('.', childid, i1 + 1) END i2) c2
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN i2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CHARINDEX('.', childid, i2 + 1) END i3) c3
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN i3 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CHARINDEX('.', childid, i3 + 1) END i4) c4
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN i4 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CHARINDEX('.', childid, i4 + 1) END i5) c5
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN i1 = 0 THEN childid ELSE SUBSTRING(childid, 1, i1 - 1) END,
        CASE WHEN i2 = 0 THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(childid, i1 + 1, i2 - i1 - 1) END,
        CASE WHEN i3 = 0 THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(childid, i2 + 1, i3 - i2 - 1) END,
        CASE WHEN i4 = 0 THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(childid, i3 + 1, i4 - i3 - 1) END,
        CASE WHEN i5 = 0 THEN '0' ELSE SUBSTRING(childid, i4 + 1, i5 - i4 - 1) END
```

Each `cross apply` is for getting next value between dots.
Downside of this approach is that it is not dynamic and you should add as many `cross applies` as there could be nesting levels.

Comment: what happends if childid contains letters ?

Comment: It will just do an alphanumeric order.

Comment: but if the number of . is more then we need to use more cross apply ??

Comment: ok i will check , but it is difficult to mention the number of cross apply manually . thanks and +1 for your suggestions .