# How can I lexicographically sort numbers stored in a string?

Tags: sql, sorting, hadoop, hive

I have a list of numbers in string format that look like this:

> 1-1
>  1-11
>  1-12
>  1-2
>  1-21 
>  1-2-31

I want to sort it it such that I get the output in the below format.

> 1-1
>  1-2
>  1-2-31
>  1-11
>  1-12
>  1-21

I have to do this sorting in Hive. How can I  achieve this?

Comment: Cut the first substring using delimiter `-`, convert to int, same for the second part.Hive must have some functions for this operation.

Comment: So you don't want lexicographical ordering.

Comment: In a string the default order is lexicographical. So you add ORDER BY yourfield to get the desired result

Comment: @JoeTaras, just imagine one of the entries has got `10-1`. Simple alphanumerical sorting would not be enough...

Comment: Btw: On the first look I got it wrong. It is absolutely usual to state what you have and **second** what you want. In your question you state the expected result **first**. No mistake on your side, clearly stated there, but as a hint for others :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

First I use a declared table variable as a **mock-up* for a test scenario.

The CTE will cut the numbers at the hyphen. Then use an **numerical** sort on both parts separately.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(StringNumber VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('1-1')
,('1-2')
,('1-11')
,('1-12')
,('1-21');

WITH Parted AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(StringNumber,pos.Hyph-1) AS PartOne
          ,SUBSTRING(StringNumber,pos.Hyph+1,1000) AS PartTwo
          ,StringNumber
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('-',StringNumber) ) AS Pos(Hyph)
)
SELECT * FROM Parted
ORDER BY CAST(PartOne AS INT),CAST(PartTwo AS INT)
```

Comment: Sorry, I answered to fast... Did not realise, that this was not SQL-Server. I let my answer here, as you see the general approach and for sure you will be able to transfer this concept...

Comment: This CTE seems to be perfect. But my column actually contains a variable number of numbers separated by hyphens. How can I make your code dynamic to accomodate this. eg, values like 3-1-3-2, 2-1-3-28-7 may also exist.

Comment: @SakshamArora I have no experience with your tools. In SQL Server one would use some kind of `string-split` (v2016+ natively, below with XML, recursive CTE or loop). Would this work for you? Find something similar (SQL-Server-syntax) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37061143/5089204) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733141/5089204)